# How to "dynamize" Dockerfile / Docker Compose?

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, xdebug

I'm Dockerizing legacy PHP project. I would like to have Xdebug enabled in development environment and my Dockerfile copies pre-built php.ini into container.

Due to some network issues we have to have `xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0` on Mac OS X (and corresponding `xdebug.remote_host = docker.for.mac.localhost`) and `xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1` on Linux.

Is it possible to grab current OS type in Dockerfile/Docker Compose to copy php.ini corresponding to host OS?

Answer (score 1):

That information isn't (and shouldn't) be available at image build time.  The same Linux-based image could be run on native Linux, a Linux VM on Mac (and then either the Docker Machine VM or the hidden VM provided by Docker for Mac), a Linux VM on Windows, or even a Linux VM on Linux, regardless of where it was originally built.

Configuration such as host names should be provided at container run time.  Environment variables are a typical way to do this, or you can use the Docker volume mechanism to push in configuration files from the host.

If your issue is purely around *debugging* your application, you can also set up a full development environment on your host, and only build in to your image the things you need to run it in a more production-like environment.

Answer (score 1):

Use `volumes` [described here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference) in `docker-compose.yml`. Create `php.linux.ini` and `php.mac.ini` in a `config` folder (or wherever) and map one of them to the container:

```
services:
  php:
    image: php
    volumes:
      - ./config/php.linux.ini:/etc/php.ini #or wherever the config is
```

Of course your users will have to manually change `php.linux.ini` for `php.mac.ini`, but it's a one time manual change.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use Docker Compose ability of reading `.env` files. The whole workflow is as following:

- create `.env.sample` file with all the lines commented *(sorry, couldn't manage to correctly display commented lines)*:

  `OS=windows
  OS=linux
  OS=mac`
- ignore `.env` file by adding `/.env` line to `.gitignore` file
- copy sample file with `$ cp .env.sample .env` and leave uncommented just one line corresponding to your OS
- move OS-specific Xdebug-related section of php.ini into separate file with names like `xdebug-mac.ini`, `xdebug-windows.ini`, `xdebug-linux.ini`, etc.
- add to `docker-compose.yml` `args` section to chosen service with value like `- OS=${OS}`
- in corresponding `Dockerfile` add lines:

  `ARG OS=${OS}
  COPY ./xdebug-${OS}.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.g/`

OS value mentioned in `.env` will be expanded on building image time

- execute `$ docker-compose up -d --build` to build image and start container
- commit all your changes on success to let your colleagues have Xdebug set properly on any platform; don't forget to tell them make their own instance of `.env` file from template